# JavaDB administration tools

Tags: derby, javadb

My current employer wants to use JavaDB for his new project. Allright with it, as my favoured SQLite isn't working very well with java and I, er..., don't really feel like arguing about it. Anyway I can't find a decent free tool to manipulate JavaDB or Derby databases. All I have is Netbeans. I've tried others but all the free ones are really tame tools and the pricy ones are good, but my employer doesn't want to pay a dyme (......).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: I second the recommendation for SQL Squirrel.

Answer (score 5):

Been looking for one too. I'm currently eying on this one http://www.razorsql.com

Comment: You will need to purchase a license in order to use razorsql.